# Export Schema and Data in Microsoft SQL Server Management Express

Tags: sql-server-2005

How to export a database schema ***and*** the data in Microsoft SQL Server Management Express? In other words given a database and the data, I want to create an .sql script that will recreate the table structure and the data inside it.

Answer (score 1):

This can't easily be done within the SQL Express Tools.

If you're willing to look at other tools, have a look at the [Database Publishing Wizard](http://sqlhost.codeplex.com/Wiki/View.aspx?title=Database%20Publishing%20Wizard) from the [SQL Server Hosting Toolkit](http://www.codeplex.com/sqlhost). It's an open-source which will script a database and data into a single script.

Answer (score 0):

Go to:
\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn
and run:
DTSWizard.exe

example, mine is:
H:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\DTSWizard.exe

Thats all

Comment: Good tips, but I don't have the folder DTSWizard.exe, is it because my version is express edition?